Solving $\int_0^\infty{f(x,x_o) \lambda(x) dx} = 0$ for $\lambda(x)$, such that this is satisfied for all $x_o$ for a known $f(x,x_o)$
How would one solve the following functional equation for a strictly nonnegative function $\lambda(x)$:
$$\int_0^\infty{f(x,x_o) \lambda(x) dx} = 0$$
if this condition holds for all $x_o$, given a specific function $f(x,x_o)$.
An obvious solution is $\lambda(x) = 0$ over the entire domain, but I am looking for other solutions.
I have solved a similar problem with an integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ via integration by parts with
$$f(x,x_o) = \left(x_o - x - \frac{x_o - x}{|x_o - x|}\right)$$
yielding
$\lambda(x) = 1$ if $|x| \leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise.
However, I am not sure how to generalise this to any function $f(x,x_o)$. Is this possible?
Thank you for your help :>

Unless you have some relation or restriction between $f(x,x_a)$ and $f(x,x_b)$, you're really just trying to solve the $\int f(x) \lambda(x), dx=0$ problem, for the many function slices at different $x_0$.
